# iText fails to propery merge signatures in PDF files

Tags: itext

I have a problem with merging PDF files using iText. I am using the PdfCopyFields class to do the merging yet, the signatures of existing PDF files are not merged properly. It seems that some data in the dictionary of the merged PDF file are incorrect.

To be specific:
I have 2 documents i want to merge, each document has 2 pages, each page in each document is signed with a different signature (in each signature i put a different reason code in order to be able to visually tell each signature).

The merged PDF file contains:

- 4 PDF pages (this is correct)
- All 4 pages have a signature
- The signature of pages 3 and 4 are NOT the original signatures, but they are the same signatures as those of page 1 and 2. To verify that the signatures are different i put a unique 'Reason' code in the signature.

It is obvious that although the resulting PDF has 4 signatures (which i know are PDF fields), it seems that these signature-fields reference the signature data of the wrong document.

Moreover, when i open the merged pdf file with a text editor, i look at the 'header' of the PDF file and find only 2 Signature entries (instead of 4). This means that the actual signatures in the pages reference only those 2 signatures, thus the mix-up.

Thank you
Costas

PS: i can post sample PDF files to reproduce the error, but the simplest ones will do the job (i created 2 PDF files with MS Word and stamped each page separately)

Comment: You cannot *merge* two documents with signatures and hope to keep them valid.

Comment: Sure, i cannot do that. This is not what i asked, i don't want to have valid signatures. The problem i describe has to do with the actual fields being mixed-up. OF COURSE the signatures will be invalid.

Comment: If the missing signature values is your focal issue, please share sample files, both source and result. It might be due to coinciding field names, but it also might be due to some other reason.

Comment: thank you. I shared a zip in the following post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Concerning the observation

> The signature of pages 3 and 4 are NOT the original signatures, but they are the same signatures as those of page 1 and 2. To verify that the signatures are different i put a unique 'Reason' code in the signature.

That might happen if the names of the signature fields in the documents coincide. Multiple PDF fields with the same name are considered multiple visualizations of the same field. The merge process may throw away duplicate values in that case.

I'm not sure, though, whether that is the case for your files. If you want to know, please share them.

...

Having inspected the sample files it becomes clear that indeed the problem is caused by the identical signature field names in the merged documents:

- Doc1-signed.pdf has

  - a signed signature field `Signature1` (field and widget merged) on page 1 with **Reason** *Doc1-Page1* in its value and
  - a signed signature field `Signature2` (field and widget merged) on page 2 with **Reason** *Doc1-Page2* in its value.
- Doc2-signed.pdf has

  - a signed signature field `Signature1` (field and widget merged) on page 1 with **Reason** *Doc2-Page1* in its value and
  - a signed signature field `Signature2` (field and widget merged) on page 2 with **Reason** *Doc2-Page2* in its value.

Merging result in MERGED-PDF.pdf which has

- a signed signature field `Signature1` with **Reason** *Doc1-Page1* in its value with explicit widgets on pages 1 and 3 and
- a signed signature field `Signature2` with **Reason** *Doc1-Page2* in its value with explicit widgets on pages 2 and 4.

Because the whole PDF is considered a single form, a form field name can only have a single associated value.

Thus, merging multiple fields with the same name from the two source documents into a single fields with multiple widgets (as `PdfCopyFields` seems to do) is a sensible action to take.

> I tried using an online pdf merge service and the signature fields were merged properly

By *merged properly* I assume you mean they still had their original, differing values. This in turn indicates that that service did not merge the fields as described above.

But this is not more *proper* than what `PdfCopyFields` does, it is dumber because the value of the field Signature1 now is unclear, just like the value of Signature2.

The *proper* thing to do if you want to keep the differing values of the source fields with duplicate names, is to **rename such duplicate fields** in the course of the merge. (If the online PDF merge service did this, too, it was not dumb. But you did not indicate any change in field names...)

You can find sample code for a merge of documents with their fields renamed in [iText in Action](http://itextpdf.com/book/) [chapter 6](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=6) Working with existing PDFs example [ConcatenateForms2.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=127):

```
    PdfCopyFields copy
        = new PdfCopyFields(new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
    // add a document
    PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(renameFieldsIn(DATASHEET, 1));
    copy.addDocument(reader1);
    // add a document
    PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(renameFieldsIn(DATASHEET, 2));
    copy.addDocument(reader2);
    // Close the PdfCopyFields object
    copy.close();
    reader1.close();
    reader2.close();
```

using the helper method

```
private static byte[] renameFieldsIn(String datasheet, int i)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // Create the stamper
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(datasheet), baos);
    // Get the fields
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    // Loop over the fields
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>(form.getFields().keySet());
    for (String key : keys) {
        // rename the fields
        form.renameField(key, String.format("%s_%d", key, i));
    }
    // close the stamper
    stamper.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Obviously you can tweak this by only renaming signature fields. This would merge other fields with "normal" form content but leave signatures as they are.

> (remember, i don't refer to the validity of the signatures themselves, just the signature fields).

As an afterthought, flattening the signature fields before merging might be an alternative approach. The visual representation remains but the verification failure messages are gone because nothing is verified anymore.

## A general remark on merging signed PDFs

Your intention

> I have 2 documents i want to merge, each document has 2 pages, each page in each document is signed with a different signature

cannot be implemented without completely invalidating the signatures, at least those from all but one document. Have a look [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) for an introduction to integrated PDF signatures. Especially note how multiple integrated signatures in the same document work:

[image: Schematic of multiple integrated PDF signatures]

After a merge of two documents, you can keep the signatures from one document valid, but the added signatures of the other document only cover data from their document while after the merge they would have to cover data from both documents.

Thus, a merge is impossible without breaking at least some of the signatures.

## Merging in more current iText versions

The OP uses an iText version 4.2.0. In current iText versions (5.5.x) much of the form aware logic has been moved from `PdfCopyFields` to `PdfCopy`. If you use such a version or a newer one, try and use `PdfCopy`.

## @Bruno on merging signature fields

The result of the merge above will be utterly invalid in PDF-2, not merely because of the invalid signatures themselves but because of the signatures with multiple appearances. You might want to reconsider the behavior of the `Pdf*Copy*` class family concerning signature fields.

Comment: Here is a link to a zip containing the 2 zip files and the merged PDF: [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C5DCD865E294FE55!779&authkey=!ACneyKM8-a96lqs&ithint=file%2czip). I tried using an online pdf merge service and the signature fields were merged properly (remember, i don't refer to the validity of the signatures themselves, just the signature fields).

Comment: Your updated answer makes things clear. This is exactly what i was looking for. Unfortunately i don't know the details of the pdf internal structure, but i understand what the problem is here. I also understand how the online pdf merge utility may have handled this case (by renaming the signature fields). I will try your suggestion with renaming signature fields. Thank you.